# Html elements toolbar for phpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I downloaded the trial version of phpStorm 10 which includes all the features of WebStorm related to HTML, CSS and JavaScript. But I couldn't find a shortcut toolbar for html or css anywhere ? It doesn't even contain indentation tool buttons :(

Is it possible to somehow have a netbeans like html elements toolbar for phpStorm ?

Comment: *"Is it possible to somehow have a netbeans like html elements toolbar for phpStorm ?"* There is simply no actions to create specific HTML elements -- you can use [Emmet](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Generating+Code+in+PhpStorm#GeneratingCodeinPhpStorm-Emmet%28ZenCoding%29) or [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) for that. But you can always create macros for such stuff and place it on toolbar if so desired.

Comment: *"It doesn't even contain indentation tool buttons :("* It's not so hard to remember and press Tab/Shift+Tab -- pretty common shortcuts for such stuff in any editor.